# getting the uploaded file

Tags: php, fine-uploader

I would like to implement delete functionality that will delete the current uploaded file.

How can I grab the current uploaded file?

Here's what I have in my javascript:

```
$('.deleteButton').click(function (){ 
             $imagefile = '../uploads/cv.jpg';
            //Make ajax call
            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
              data:{
                        action: 'deleteButton',
                        imagefile: $imagefile,
                    },
                    url: "php/deleteImage.php"
            });


        });
```

My PHP file:

```
  <?php
        if($_POST["action"]=="deleteButton") {
                 $imagefile = $_REQUEST['imagefile'];
          unlink($imagefile);
    }
  ?>
```

Now, instead of putting a static value for $imagefile, I want to grab the uploaded file.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the [delete file feature](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/delete-uploaded-file-in-33.html) in Fine Uploader?

Comment: I ddnt know that... OK, s oI read the your post on delete. So, do you also have the php script that for the delete? I only saw the javascript function. Please let me know, thanks

Comment: I don't have a PHP example that shows how to handle Fine Uploader's DELETE request server-side at this point.  The only server-side example that contains DELETE handling is the java example.  My blog post explains, at a high-level, how to handle the DELETE request sent by Fine Uploader.  You can use that to construct your PHP code.

Comment: Can you share the link please

Comment: Which specific link are you looking for?

Comment: nevermind, its the same link you shared

Comment: is there a way to know the file selected using javascript ?

Comment: Are you asking how you can determine which file the user has elected to delete client-side?  If you are using FineUploader mode, you don't need to worry about this.  Fine Uploader takes care of it for you.  Simply enable the feature and handle the DELETE request server-side.